# Testing: PHP + PostgreSQL with SQLite

Tags: php, database, postgresql, laravel, sqlite

We have an old system built on a modified Laravel 3 engine and PostgreSQL database.
I would like to create a test for reading from the database with PhpUnit.
It would be great, if I could use the :memory: SQLite database connection.

How can I create a schema like structure in SQLite when I would like to test not the public one?

My function which should be tested contains queries like:

```
$connection->table('myschema.tablename')->get();
```

When the test would create a myschema.tablename table, it fails, as in the SQLite database we don't have database with the name of myschema.
When I create the test DB without schema, the test fails as the class is not able to select from it, the myschema.mtablename does not exist.

So my question is:
How do you test PostgreSQL with memory SQLite?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Is your old app has migrations file in it? You can just run `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` every time the test started.

Comment: No, unfortunately we don't have migrations, we store raw sql files, as the modifications are postgre specific and difficult.